# Executing multiple queries in Nodejs route

Tags: mysql, node.js, post, async-await

I have Node.js post route in which I am executing several queries in sequence with async/await.

```
router.post("/foo", async (req, res) => {
    const qr1 = "str1";
    await db.query(qr1); // Works fine
    const qr2 = "str2";
    await db.query(qr2); // Works fine
    const qr3 = "str3";
    await db.query(qr3, async (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        if (result.length > 0) {
            // Required data is received – That part works
            // do something and continue to step 4
        }
    });
    // step 4 – Never gets here
});
```

All queries which perform table manipulation i.e. delete, insert etc work fine. Once I get to a select query I receive the required data but i need to continue to the next step which doesn't happen. 
I know I can accomplish what I need by nesting step 4 within step 3, but I would like to know if there is a different way to do that.

Comment: The request/response cycle ends when you send back response. Are you sure inside the function you are not calling res.send() or something like that.

Comment: @khan I checked that. I don't believe I do.

Comment: What do you use to query the database - i.e. are you sure your lib's `db.query` returns a promise?

Comment: @StockOverflaw. Just a simple MySQL select query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that comment **// step 4** is executed immediately whereas the async(err code is executed asynchronously when query 3 executes.  Here is your code corrected to achieve your result:

```
router.post("/foo", async (req, res) => {
try {
  const qr1 = "str1";
  await db.query(qr1); // Works fine
  const qr2 = "str2";
  await db.query(qr2); // Works fine
  const qr3 = "str3";
  const q3Result = await db.query(qr3);
  console.log('step 4');
  // step 4 – Should work fine
}
catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}

});
```